# Yielding the result of a subscription stream

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream, dart-async

I am a beginner in Dart streams. I have a method which should return the connectivity result or an exception using the [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package.

```
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  ConnectivityResult _result = ConnectivityResult.none;

  Stream<Either<ValueFailure, ConnectivityResult>> watchConnectivity() async* {
    try {
      _result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
      _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
        // Got a new connectivity status!
        _result = result;
      });
      yield right(_result);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      yield Left(ValueFailure.connectivityError(failMessage: e.message));
    }
  }
```

Currently the 'yield right(_result)' statement does not yield anything after a new event occurs inside the connectivity stream subscription. How should I rewrite the code so that every time there is a connection status update the stream yields a result or failure?

Comment: you should trigger new event when `_result = result;` - that is inside `onConnectivityChanged.listen` callback - but actually if `onConnectivityChanged` is a stream why not to use it directly (instead of using `listen()` method)?

Comment: You mean something like this? ( ` yield* _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.map((ConnectivityResult result) => right(result));` )

Comment: more or less, you can just return `_connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.map((ConnectivityResult result) => right(result));` - no need for `yield*` and `async*` method

Comment: and instead of `Stream.map` you could also use `Stream.transform` and pass a param of `StreamTransformer.fromHandlers()` where you can handle both data and errors